# Pascal Calculator

Tags: calculator, pascal

I am now developing a calculator in Pascal and I am getting this error that while the exponent is negative the result is always 0. Can someone help me with this?
Here is the piece of code for this function that I wrote so far:

```
5: Begin
    clrscr;
    Writeln('POWER');
    Write('Base: ');
    Readln(pot1);
    Write('Exponent: ');
    Readln(pot2);
    res5 := 1;
    if pot2 < 0 then
     Begin
        pot1 := 1 div pot1;
        pot2 := -pot2;
        res5 := 1 / res5;
     End;
    while pot2 > 0 do
        Begin
          res5 := res5 * pot1;
          pot2 := pot2 - 1;
        End;
        Writeln('The result is: ', res5:0:4);
        Readkey;
   End;
```

Comment: Read the docs first https://wiki.freepascal.org/Div

Comment: div is integer division. use / instead.

Comment: @Martheen Just for the sake of completeness: The pages in the mentioned wiki are not _the_ documentation, but [here is FPC’s documentation](https://www.freepascal.org/docs.var). Maybe some [easier explanation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Special:PermaLink/4033939#Division).